# Circle ImageView onClickListener not working

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-studio-3.0

circle image view onclick listener is not working every solution on this site for that is tried but issue is not solved i am posting the code please guide me thanks

```
private CircleImageView setupImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);

    Toolbar setupToolbar = findViewById(R.id.setupToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(setupToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Account Setup");


    setupImage = findViewById(R.id.setup_image);
    setupImage.setClickable(true);

    setupImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SetupActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "You Already Have Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }

        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: What device are you testing on? More to the point what Android version? Also, have you tested that the click listener itself fires without doing the internal if checks?

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little about what is not working? Any errors you can share?

Comment: here is the activity.xml file for cirlceImageview  {  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/setup_image"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="189dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/default_profile"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setupToolbar" />}

Comment: @IvanWooll i m using HTC desire 626 Android 5.1 not any error but when i click on circleViewImage for which in my activity i use onClickListener but when i click on this imageView nothing happen basically i am using this imageView for my users to set there own profile picture i want to implement that when a user click on it it will access phone gallary and a user can select his profile picture but its not working as u see the code there is no error

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library :    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

activity_main.xml

```
  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

main.java

```
CircleImageView circleImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    circleImageView = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    circleImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi here is my setup.xml code for circleIMAGEVIEW

{  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/setup_image"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="189dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/default_profile"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setupToolbar" />}

Comment: so! what's an issue

Comment: when i click on this imageview during testing the app it should access my phone gallery to upload a profile pic but when i click on this image view nothing happen

Comment: because now you have to function that pick image from the user.Just google it... you will get many tutorials which might help you :)

Comment: thanks sir you are just great and help me solve my problem u r awesome thanks